# How to type data from list to a website using python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Im a complete beginner in coding and i want to enter data to a specific website from a list and keep track of that data, using python and selenium. Current code that is used is>

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
inputElement.send_keys("example@email.com")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
inputElement.send_keys("passwordexample")
```

Im trying to replace "example@email.com" "passwordexample" with data from the list list, if the data format is something like:

- example@email.com:passwordexample
- example2@email.com:passwordexample2

I dont know how to make that list and how to take data line by line from that list one by one

Comment: is the q answered?

Comment: Yeah i got it working but in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did i solve this problem? - First there is file with username:password format.
I made 2 other seperate text files called for example, username.txt and password.txt

Then i used regex to count words in a line, then using counted value to split the text where i wanted, since my text could be something like :

- user name:password
- us er name:password
- us_er.name:password

and so on. Since password never has any space between words, always last word is password.

```
import regex

lineinfo = open("allaccounts.txt", "r")

username = open("username.txt", "w")
password = open("password.txt", "w")
info = lineinfo.readline()
info2 = info.replace(':', ' ')
count = len(regex.findall(r'\S+', info2))
if count == 2:
    info3 = info2.split()[0]
    username.write(info3)
    info4 = info2.split()[1]
    password.write(info4)

if count == 3:
    info3 = info2.split()[0]
    info5 = info2.split()[1]
    username.write(info3 + " " + info5)
    info4 = info2.split()[2]
    password.write(info4)

username.close() and password.close()
username = open("username.txt", "r")
password = open("password.txt", "r")
real_username = username.readline()
real_password = password.readline()
username.close()
password.close()
```

Yeah maybe this can be done in a much easier way but i started learining code like 4 days ago and this is what i could come up in the spot.

so the username will be rea_username and password real_password and i used them like

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
inputElement.send_keys("real_username")
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
inputElement.send_keys("real_password")
```

Comment: If you don't do this replace - `replace(':', ' ')`, you can do the split on the colon - `split(':')`, and the first element is going to be the user, and the second - the pass. The regex is also not going to be needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that you mean that you want to create a storage (in this case a dictionary) for the e-mails and passwords.

```
my_dict = {example@email.com: passwordexample, 
           example2@email.com: passwordexample2,
           example3@email.com: passwordexample3}
```

Again, not sure what you mean by "list" (doesn't seem like you are referring to an actual python list). Also not sure what you mean by "take data."

You are also going to want to change the variable name for either the username or password box. So maybe more like this:

```
inputElement_user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
inputElement_pass = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
# Loop through every user & pass and do what you wish
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    inputElement_user.send_keys(k)
    inputElement_pass.send_keys(v)
    # Insert whatever else you want to do on the page
```

Answer (score 1):

no clarity from where this 'example@email.com:passwordexample' comes from assuming it is as string you can achieve it usng split() method

```
data = "example@email.com:passwordexample"

#seperate values using : seperator from the string
datalist = data.split(':')

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
#use index on list to get required value datalist[0] will give you example@email.com
inputElement.send_keys("datalist[0]")

inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
#datalist[1] will give you passwordexample
inputElement.send_keys("datalist[1]")
```

Comment: Yes that data comes is just a string atm and its for testing purposes atm. Lets say i do have 1000 lines of data to input. I could make an variable for data and split it the way u just showed, but it would be clearly too time consuming to index every piece of data manually.

Comment: @syinncc use for loop